# The meaning of straight jacket

Tags: definition

> As I neared my house, the memory of the previous night at the shop
>   came flooding back to the forefront of my mind. Did I really see
>   Olivia in my mom’s shop? How was that possible?
>
> I contemplated telling my mother about what I had seen in case I
>   needed help or something. What if I started seeing other people, like
>   my dad? I was sure that would make me go crazy for real, and I needed
>   someone there to support me when they put on the **straight jacket**.
>
> When I entered the house, my mom was already preparing lunch. “I’m
>   not hungry,” I told her.

This text is from the book *Fire in Frost*.

I could not understand the meaning of **straight jacket**.

Comment: Try a dictionary search for ['straightjacket'](https://www.onelook.com/?w=straightjacket&ls=a).

Comment: I assuming they meant [*Strait Jacket*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straitjacket)

Comment: I always thought it was a 'strait' (narrow, tight) jacket. Dickens mentions a 'strait-waistcoat'.

Comment: Did you try to look it up?

Comment: It's the same word as _strait_ for a narrow body of water.  The only other current usage that comes to mind is _strait-laced_, which likewise is often written with _gh_.

Answer (score 24):

The traditional spelling is *[straitjacket](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/straitjacket)*.  It is a garment that has long sleeves that can be tied securely behind the back, preventing the person wearing the straitjacket from using their hands. It was used to prevent violent, mentally ill patients from injuring themselves or others (from an old word "strait" meaning "restricted, narrow, tight-fitting").

"When they put on the straitjacket" means when people from the mental asylum come to take me to away. Here it is meant figuratively.

Comment: As this NGram graph shows, there is considerable flexibility in the spelling of this word, and it seems to have changed over time. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=strait+jacket%2C+strait-jacket%2C+straitjacket%2C+straight+jacket&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstrait%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstrait%20-%20jacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstraitjacket%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstraight%20jacket%3B%2Cc0. Note that the Cambridge DIctionary contains an entry for Straightjacket. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/straightjacket

Comment: Ok, edited.  A learner should generally be conservative about spelling innovations such as straight for strait. So I've written "the traditional spelling".

Comment: @JavaLatte: Re "flexibility in the spelling", it might be more accurate to say that a lot of people (and these days, spell-checkers) simply don't know how to spell the word correctly :-)

Comment: No, @jamesqf. That is a different formulation - a more conservative one, perhaps. I strongly deny that it is a more _accurate_ one.

Comment: @ColinFine Agreed. Language changes over time. That's just the way it is.

Comment: Having looked at this discussion, I've decided to stick with my current formulation of "the traditional spelling" I think this suggests to a learner which spelling they should use while recognising that there is some variation.

Comment: How about “the etymological spelling”?

Comment: No, I think I'll stick to what I've got.